# When moving an Agent from a non-local Faction, what is the correct orientation?

Tags: the-agents

This came up in a three player game, but I think it'd be even worse in 4 or 5.  One of the Free Agents ("The Interloper" maybe?) has the power "Move one Agent from any Faction into a neighboring Faction."  I think it was neighboring, it might have been to any other one.

Since you could (and probably would) be moving from a non-adjacent faction, how would you preserve the orientation?  If the command faces a player on one side and you move it to a neighboring faction, the command still has to face that player, yes?

What if the card did say move from "any faction to any faction?"  How would orientation be preserved then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, the command would still face the same player**

The [rules](http://thoughtprocess.me/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/rules_08_PnP1.pdf) state the following on the very last page, FAQ section:

> When swapping two Agents, their orientation must remain the same! I.e. players cannot turn Agents when swapping them. For example, **if an Agent‘s command was facing you before the swap, it must still be facing you after the swap.**

Cards only have two orientations, Commands towards you or data-token halves towards you.

> Each Agent card features a command giving the player a special ability. When placing an Agent onto a Faction, you choose whether to face the command towards yourself or towards another player. [...] The other end of the card features data-token halves (either black or white). When these halves are joined together, they award intel points to whomever their arrows are facing. **Your decision when placing a card on a Faction, therefore, is in which direction to place the card - whether to keep the command for yourself, or try to give yourself intel points by completing data tokens.**

There is no way to preserve orientation if you move an agent to a non-adjacent faction, since a non-adjacent faction would not be shared by player it was being moved into. The only way for such a card to exist would likely be if you were allowed to turn the agents orientation to whichever way you wished after moving it.

Answer (score 0):

The Interloper states "**MOVE an agent from any faction to any neighboring faction**" and the limitation of "neighboring" was very deliberate since you *can* still maintain the orientation of the card facing for the player that is sitting between those two neighboring factions.

There is no card that allows moving of a card from any faction to any faction.